# Would like to do a mercurial clone with filter of patterns in hgignore

Tags: mercurial, clone, partial

Over time a number of the developers have committed files that were then added to the .hgignore.  From what I hear there is no way to remove items from the history of mercurial, which is ok.  But I also heard that there is a way to do a clone, I think using the convert plugin, to clone/export a repo while specifying which files to not include in the conversion.

I can't help but think that someone out there has a script that does this export/filter/convert using the patterns from the .hgignore file.

Has anyone created such a beast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a filemap from .hgignore doing something like this:

```
hg clone -U yourrepo temprepo # create a temp repo with no files in working dir
cd tmprepo
hg revert --all # put files in working dir
hg forget **   # un-add the files
hg status --ignored --no-status | sed 's/^/exclude /' > ../filemap
```

that will get you a filemap you can pass into `hg convert` that removes all the added files that would be ignored given your .hgignore.

Do understand though, that running convert creates a whole new repo that is unrelated to your previous repo.  All existing clones will be unusable with the new one.  It's not normally worth it.

Comment: Ok so this is really good, will try it.  I understand about the existing clones will not be usable, however I think in our current model this should be ok.  We do have a central repo that everyone pushes to, and that the build system works from.  Noone has any long standing commits that are not pushed.  So we could call a flag day, do the clone and then have everyone pull.

Comment: One quick question, what happens to history and branch names and such, I assume that the convert will keep all these things.  Will do some reading on it to see if that is the case.

Comment: Now to figure out how to say that 2 answers are the correct ones, this one gives me one piece, and the other gives the other pieces :)

Answer (score 2):

hg convert is indeed the thing you want to use.

You will want to create a file map (just a text file) which will list all of the things you either want to include, exclude, or rename:

```
include subfolder
exclude subfolder/supersub
etc...
```

Read the following for a more concrete example:
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#A--filemap

Once you have created this file you will just use the following command:

`$ hg convert --filemap my_file_map /path/to/source/repo /path/to/dest/repo`

The source repo will not be modified and a dest repo will be created. I don't want to just copy verbatim what the documentation already says so here is the link:

How to keep just a subdirectory (or run on the mercurial repo):
https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension#Converting_from_Mercurial

Comment: So that part I get, however how do I create the filemap from the .hgignore.  Thats the part I guess I should have asked for.  There has to be a script of some kind to create the filemap for the hgignore file.  Time for google :)

Comment: Looks like there is some discussion about the ability to add regular expressions to the filemap command, but I dont where it got to http://groups.google.com/group/mercurial_general/browse_thread/thread/cf53f593a4f771c0?pli=1